# Querying against multiple values with Django Querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset, geodjango

I have a `Foo` and a `Bar` model. Each model has a GeoDjango `point` attribute. I would like to have returned a query set that contains all `Bar`s within a 2 Kilometer radius of *any* `Foo`. There are roughly 5000 `Foo`s and 900 `Bar`s so any exhaustive solution will take a long time, such as my current solution:

```
query = Q()
radius = 2
for foo in Foo.objects.iterator():
    if foo.point:   
        point = foo.point
        query = query | Q(point__distance_lt=(point, radius))

bars = Bar.objects.filter(query)
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Or have I made any mistakes that make it incalculable?